# Get all page titles on Wikipedia that contain a specific word

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am writing [an "auto-wikifier" tool](http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/gjqWy/78/) using HTML and JavaScript. For each word in the text to be wikified, I need to obtain a list of pages that contain that word (so that the matching phrases in the text can be automatically wikified, if they are found). Is there a way to obtain a list of all Wikipedia pages that contain a specific word, using one of Wikipedia's APIs or web services?

```
function getMatchingPageTitles(theString){
    //get a list of all matching page titles for a specific string, using one of Wikipedia's APIs or web services
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia or MediaWiki? That makes a huge difference. ie. wikipedia.org or some custom installation of MediaWiki.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm only concerned with obtaining the page titles from .

Comment: There's like 4M+ Wikipedia articles; I'm not convinced the browser won't crash.

Comment: You want all 4,149,223 titles in an array?

Comment: You can download the entire wikipedia database and do this offline using any lang of your choice. Maybe perl, since you'll be doing a lot of parsing.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm pretty sure the browser will.

Comment: @techfoobar Downloading the entire database would be overkill - I only want to download the list of page titles.

Comment: overkill? no, it wouldn't be overkill. what would be overkill is trying to use an API and javascript to obtain 4 million wikipedia entries. Why don't you explain what you actually want to achieve, there is probably a better way around it.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - You can try to locate their sitemap files and parse the links off from them.

Comment: @Prisoner Of course not. The question says “all page titles”, that means all 29 million pages, not just the 4 million articles.

Comment: @svick silly me, what was I thinking..

Comment: @svick I changed the wording of the question - I realized that it would be much more efficient to simply obtain a list of matching page titles for each word in the text to wikify.

Comment: I added tags #sparql #dbpedia to your question, may help too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[First](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First), [I'm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m) [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not) [sure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sure) [I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I) [understand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Understand) [how](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How) [would](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Would) [something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something) [like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like) [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That) [be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be) [useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useful). (Wikipedia has articles for all the common words and I don't think links to them would be of any use.)

But if you really wanted to do something like this, I think a much better way would be to use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to find out which words from your input text have articles.

For example, for the string `I am writing an "auto-wikifier" tool`, your query could look something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=I|am|writing|an|auto-wikifier|tool

And the answer is:

```
<api>
  <query>
    <normalized>
      <n from="am" to="Am" />
      <n from="writing" to="Writing" />
      <n from="an" to="An" />
      <n from="auto-wikifier" to="Auto-wikifier" />
      <n from="tool" to="Tool" />
    </normalized>
    <pages>
      <page ns="0" title="Auto-wikifier" missing="" />
      <page pageid="2513432" ns="0" title="Am" />
      <page pageid="2513422" ns="0" title="An" />
      <page pageid="25346998" ns="0" title="I" />
      <page pageid="30677" ns="0" title="Tool" />
      <page pageid="32977" ns="0" title="Writing" />
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

Few notes:

- The results are not in the order you specified them.
- If a page doesn't exist, the result has `missing=""` attribute.
- JSON and JSONP formats are available too, that might be more suitable for JavaScript.
- The `titles` parameter has a limit of 50 per one query.

Comment: +1 for a solution which doesn't involve bombarding a non-profit site with a bunch of pointless traffic.

Comment: Would there be a way to find all pages with titles that contain a certain word (instead of being an exact match of that word)?

Comment: You could try something like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=search&srsearch=intitle:tool&srprop=&srlimit=max, but that would mean one query for each word.

Comment: @svick You made a very good point: It would not be useful to wikify every single word that has an article on Wikipedia. Instead, it would be better to obtain a list of page titles that are contained in the input, and then ask the user whether to wikify each title (with the titles being wikified in descending order). This would avoid the inherent redundancy of fully automatic wikification, since it would allow the user to choose specific phrases to wikify.

Comment: I noticed that there is a limit of 50 results for each query. Is there a way to get all the page titles and redirect pages that contain a specific word (instead of just 50 of them)?

Answer (score 1):

The [API:Allpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aAllpages) is an interesting start. Sadly, [it is limited to 500 queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Kre&aplimit=500)

Comment: Is it possible to make search for matches of a whole word? (I noticed that [this query](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Kre&aplimit=500) shows all pages that contain `Kre`, not just `Kre` as a single word. Is it possible to show results for the whole word only?)

Comment: I think your trouble actually is to add spaces around Kre, within a PHP query.

Comment: Note: I also just start to dig in the mediawiki API. I guess it's a general policy to limit queries to 500, so I will head toward dbpedia & sparql queries.

Comment: I added spaces around `Kre`, and I'm still getting results like `Kreamer` and `Kreacher`. It would be better if the results only contained `Kre` as an isolated word. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=%20Kre%20&aplimit=500

Comment: Isolated spaces seems to be automatically discarded, I already noticed this behaviour in previous cases. Search online or open a SO question about this space issue.